# Does religion encompass philosophical belief in the sentencing act 2020?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-terms

In other areas of law, religion is explained to encompass philosophical belief, as well as lack of religion or lack of philosophical belief.

Whereas s66(1)(b) of the sentencing act 2020 makes simple reference to "religion," is there any basis of universalising this broader understanding of religion so that it is more broadly applicable than just in the equality act or public order act, for examples?

Comment: I wonder if the equality act itself could be used by an atheist or holder of another solemn and weighty non-religious philosophical belief that the lack of inclusion in judicial interpretation of that provision would be judicial discrimination under the human rights and equality acts and so therefore it legally must be interpreted so broadly as to encompass them?

Comment: As an aside.  To quote Calvin "Verbing weirds language"

Comment: @PeterM would you care to elaborate what is meant by this quotation?

Comment: It is a reaction to "universalising"

Comment: I'm still confused, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sentencing Act's concept of religion relates to membership of religious *groups*, not to individual beliefs. However, a group defined by lack of a religious belief would also be covered.

You noted the mention of “religious hostility” in s. 66(1)(b). However, further subsections provide additional context.

Per s. 66(4), an offence would be aggravated by religious hostility when the offender demonstrated hostility based on “the victim's membership (or presumed membership) of a religious group”, or when the offence was motivated by “hostility towards members of a religious group based on their membership of that group”.

Per s. 66(6)(b), “references to a religious group are to a group of persons defined by reference to religious belief or lack of religious belief”.

In general, philosophical opinions are not that group-defining. It would be difficult to imagine an extremist Utilitarian attacking people because they are in favour of Discourse Ethics or because they associate with Discourse Ethics proponents.

However, there isn't necessarily a bright line between religious beliefs and philosophical convictions, especially in the area of New Religious Movements. But similarly, there isn't a bright line between some philosophical convictions and political opinions, yet offences motivated by the victim's membership to a particular political group are *not* considered aggravated under s. 66 of the Sentencing Act. I suppose a court would have to look into the individual circumstances, also taking into account that religious beliefs are interpreted more broadly in other contexts.

What is clear though is that atheists are a religious group for the context of this Act, per the definition in s. 66(6)(b).

In the comments, you propose a theory that failure to cover some characteristics could be a violation of human rights. I don't think that works, since s. 66 of the Sentencing Act does not directly protect characteristics such as disability or membership to a religious groups. Instead, this section defines hate crimes, where motives such as racism or transphobia are an *aggravating factor* that makes things that are already illegal even worse.

Comment: But with respect to the last bit, on the basis of what principle (if not that of human rights) does this act define such aggravating factors to make certain hate crimes even worse?

Comment: @Joseph Not sure, you'd have to find the Explanatory Notes for the law that introduced these factors. The Sentencing Act 2020 just staples together existing laws as part of the [Law Commission's modernization effort](https://www.lawcom.gov.uk/project/sentencing-code/). They have a draft version with origins for each section. S. 66 was mostly taken from the [Crime and Disorder Act 1998](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/37/section/28/2001-12-14). Religion was added to the CDA by the [Anti-terrorism, Crime and Security Act 2001](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2001/24/section/39).